# How to create such a chapter style

Tags: memoir, chapters

I've been trying to create the chapter style shown in the image using `memoir` class but no luck with that. Can anyone help me out?[image]

Comment: Is having an epigraph supposed to be part of every chapter heading, or will there be chapter headings without epigraphs?

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Here are the necessary definitions (except for the exact font used, this can be solved using [`WhatTheFont`](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) or elsewhere). Basically, a new chapter style (a variation of the predefined `dowding` style) and some redefinitions affecting the formatting of the the built-it `\epigraph`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{mystyle}{%
  \chapterstyle{dowding}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\Large\itshape}%
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\chapnamefont}%
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\centering\chapnumfont \thechapter}%
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\huge\centering}%
}
\renewcommand{\@epitext}[1]{%
  \begin{minipage}{\epigraphwidth}\begin{\textflush}\itshape\normalsize #1\par
    \ifdim\epigraphrule>\z@ \@epirule \else \vspace*{1ex} \fi
  \end{\textflush}\end{minipage}}
\renewcommand{\@episource}[1]{%
  \begin{minipage}{\epigraphwidth}
    \begin{\sourceflush}\itshape #1\par
  \end{\sourceflush}\end{minipage}}
\makeatother

\chapterstyle{mystyle}    

\epigraphposition{center}
\epigraphsourceposition{center}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{.6\textwidth}
\begin{document}

\chapter{The Sweet Spot}
\epigraph{You will become clever through your mistakes}{---German proverb}

\end{document}
```